# The thymeleaf template now showing inner element from anchor tag

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a strange problem while populating anchor tag attributes i.e. href using thymeleaf template, the inner element of a tag are not displayed.

My code looks like below:-

```
<li class="" th:each="aMenu : ${adminMenu}">
    <a href="#" th:href="@{${aMenu.url}}"  th:title="${aMenu.menuName}"  
    th:text="${aMenu.menuName}">
    <em th:class="${aMenu.menuCss}"/>
    <span th:text="${aMenu.menuName}"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The anchor tag is displayed but it's inner element are omitted.
Can anyone please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `th:text` attribute replaces everything inside the tag. As you already have a `<span>` element with `menuName` as it's content, you can simply remove the `th:text` attribute from `<a>` tag.